# Does Superman exist? (Logical analysis)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am given as exercise to check the following reasonment:

"If superman is able to and wants to prevent evil, he will.
If superman is not able to prevent evil, then he is passed out.
If superman doesn't want to prevent evil, then he is evil.

Superman doesn't prevent evil.

If Superman exists, he is neither passed out nor evil.

Then Superman doesn't exist."

I'm a bit uncertain on how to lay out the logical analysis of this.

Comment: It's funny how they made the problem politically correct by writing "Superman" instead of "God". It's actually a famous problem in Philosophy, called "Theodicy".

Comment: Anyway, what is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to properly symbolize it; the *premises* are :

> P1) $(Able_S \land Want_S) \to Prevent_S$
>
> P2) $\lnot Able_S \to Passed_S$
>
> P3) $\lnot Want_S \to Evil_S$
>
> P4) $\lnot Prevent_S$
>
> P5) $Exists_S \to (\lnot Passed_S \land \lnot Evil_S)$

and the sought *conclusion* :

> > $\lnot Exists_S$.

---

Having said that, the sought derivation must be :

1) $\lnot Prevent_S \to (\lnot Able_S \lor \lnot Want_S)$ --- from P1) by [Contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) and [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

2) $\lnot Able_S \lor \lnot Want_S$ --- from 1) and P4) by *modus ponens*

3) $Passed_S \lor Evil_S$ --- from 2), P2) and P3) by [Constructive dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_dilemma)

4) $(Passed_S \lor Evil_S) \to \lnot Exists_S$ --- from P5) using again [Contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) and [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

> $\lnot Exists_S$ --- from 3) and 4) by *modus ponens*.

---

In alternative, you can use [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)).

Comment: So how do I proceed from there?

Comment: I wrote it as $$((Able_S \land Want_S) \to Prevent_S )\land (\lnot Able_S \to Passed_S )\land (\lnot Want_S \to Evil_S) \land( \lnot Prevent_S) \land (Exists_S \to (\lnot Passed_S \land \lnot Evil_S)))  \to  (\lnot Exists_S)$$

But then how do I verify this?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, I understand the first step, however I have some trouble with the "easily derivable" ;-). is this correct? 

$$ \lnot Prevents_S \implies \lnot(Able_S\lor Wants_S)$$
$$\iff \lnot Prevents_s \implies \lnot Able_S \lor \lnot Wants_s$$
$$\iff \lnot Prevents_S \implies Evil_S \lor Passed_S$$ ?